# Is adding root to the user group staff safe?

Tags: macos, permission, root

So it seems my library folders are owned by my user, and `staff` is the user group.

When I run commands in sudo, I get warnings from programs like `pip` that root doesn't own the folder/file.

To avoid these errors, I was thinking of filing `root` as part of the `staff` user group, then I wouldn't have any issues.

Is this safe? Why shouldn't root be a part of all user groups?

Comment: root is already a member of the group staff.